# Erro ocorrendo no Angular

Tags: angular

Bom dia!

O Angular está pedindo pra atualizar as dependências, tanto na instação quanto na criação de novos projetos:

**npm WARN deprecated angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3: angular-cli has been renamed to @angular/cli. Please update your dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated exists-sync@0.0.3: Please replace with usage of fs.existsSync**

**npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...types/minimatch":"lat'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\697343\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-10-26T13_04_31_073Z-debug.log**

Obrigado!

Comment: Olá Paulo Velosa, bem vindo ao Stack! sua pergunta esta um pouco vaga, se puder colocar o seu codigo junto com o erro, ou o print do erro, já ira nos ajudar a te ajudar!